# How to define the parity of a permutation in a finite group $G$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

> How to define the parity of a permutation in a finite group $G$?

I know that there is an isomorphism $\phi$ between $S(G)$ and a subgroup of $S_n$, so we could say $\epsilon_{G}(\sigma):=\epsilon_{S_n}(\phi(\sigma))$ for $\sigma \in S(G)$ and where $\epsilon_{S_n}$ is the usual parity function. I don't know if there is a usual way to do so.

I didn't find any reference, does someone knows a textbook that makes this generalization?

Comment: You didn't find any reference because probably noone does that. Where did you get the question from? It is unusual to say the least.

Comment: Do you mean parity of a permutation, i.e parity of the number of inversions?

Comment: @freakish The question is from me... I wanted to compute the parity of $x \in G \mapsto g x$ and this question crossed my mind.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Yes! (I changed sign to parity).

Comment: Since permutations are bijections of a set, in this case $G$, the usual definition of the signature of a permutation applies.

Comment: @Somos My definition of an inversion is that $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$, this doesn't work here.

Comment: You should maybe clarify some notations. What is $n$, what is $S(G)$?

Comment: @CaptainLama $n$ is an integer, $S(G)$ is the set of bijections of $G$.

Comment: But do you have some special $n$ in mind? Because $S(G)$ is not just isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, it is isomorphic to the whole $S_n$ for $n$ the cardinal of $G$. And that has nothing to do with $G$ being a group.

Comment: @CaptainLama No... You're right but it doesn't really help to know that...

Comment: It does, because it shows you are being confused. Your question has nothing to do with $G$ being a group, or $S(G)$ having a morphism with $S_n$. You are just trying to define the sign of a bijection of a set, which is the usual definition.

Comment: @CaptainLama And what is the usual definition please?

Comment: Any permutation is a product of transpositions, and the sign is given by the parity of the number of transpositions you use. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation. It is often done in $S_n$, but it works in any $S(X)$ where $X$ is a finite set.

Comment: @CaptainLama This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the abstract, group elements don't have a parity. You can't establish one by embedding the group in a symmetric group because that can be done in several ways. For example, you can embed $\mathbb{Z}_3$ in $S_3$ or in $S_6$ isomorphically  by sending a generator to $(123)$ or to  $(123)(456)$.

However, for the map from a group $G$ to the permutations $S_G$ of itself that sends $g$ to the permutation $x \to xg$ you can use the usual definition of parity in $S_G$.

I suggest you work out a few examples of that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question isn't about defining parity for elements of $G$ but for bijections of $G$...

Comment: ..which is exactly what the paragraph beginning "However" does.

Comment: Note, you *cannot* map $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to $S_3$ isomorphically.

Comment: @Unit Of course. I fixed the typo.